# What are the rules for when parshiyos are combined?

Tags: parsha-torah-portion

Seven pairs of *parshiyos* are combined under certain conditions. For example, *Nitzavim* and *Vayelech* are combined whenever the following Rosh Hashanah is on Thursday or Shabbos.

What are the rules for when other *parshiyos* are combined?

Comment: You just want a list of every calendar possibility and all the double parshas in it?

Comment: It's all in the Beiur Halacha 428